# Do we know all of the guarantees in the Constitution of the United Federation of Planets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

In Star Trek we know of the 7th and 12th guarantees:

> The Seventh Guarantee against self-incrimination during legal
>   proceedings was considered by Captain Picard in 2367 to be "one of the
>   most important rights granted by the Federation. (TNG: "The Drumhead")
>
> The Twelfth Guarantee of the Constitution dealt with the rights of
>   artists, and defined an artist as "a person who creates an original
>   artistic work. (VOY: "Author, Author")

Do we know the other 10 guarantees?

Comment: Nope. We know all 285 damn Rules of Acquisition, but the Federation constitution is mostly a mystery.

Comment: Well they're more like guidelines really. The so-called Prime Directive can be disregarded willy-nilly, so what of the others?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - as we all know from software development, commercial software has great documentation, whereas [free software documentation is... lacking](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/415-Open-Source-Sucks.html).

Comment: @Gaius: But the Prime Directive is a Starfleet - and not a Federation - regulation, right?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite LMAO! so true. Love it.

Answer (score 4):

### Main canon

No further mention is made of the numbered "guarantees" enshrined in the Federation Constitution in any Star Trek TV show or film.

### EU Canon

The First Guarantee is described in [Vanguard: Precipice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451687451) as the right to a fair trial and to consult with an attorney:

> “Lieutenant Jackson,” the Orion said as Captain Desai followed her
>   inside the interview room, “My name is Denon Veril. I’m Mister Kane’s
>   attorney.” She set her briefcase on the table. “I need to confer in
>   private with my client, as per his rights under the First Guarantee of
>   the Federation Charter.”

Beyond that, there are innumerable mentions of people's legal rights (the right to prevent seizure of property, the right to not be tortured, the right to food while in custody, etc etc) but no specific references to whether these are part of the **numbered guarantees**

There's also quite a nice version of the Federation Charter in the "[Starfleet Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual)" but no mention at all of numbered guarantees.