# Does the Federation have the equivalent of Miranda rights?

Tags: star-trek, laws, federation

I am watching DS9 for the first time (almost at the end of season 4) and it struck me that whenever a character is arrested, it seems that they are never told their rights and/or what they're being charged with.

> When Lt. Reese enters the room to arrest Cassidy Yates for assisting the Maquis, wouldn't he have to tell her something like "Cassidy Yates, you are under arrest for aiding and abetting terrorism. Federation law requires me to inform you that you have the right to remain silent, and that you have the right to an advocate..." etc etc.

But I've never seen anything like this in the Treks I've watched (VOY and DS9, some TNG). So, does the Federation have Miranda rights or their equivalent?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Seventh_Guarantee

Comment: Not an answer, but there are huge swathes of the Earth that don't have the equivalent of Miranda rights.  So who is to say what legal system DS9 followed.  See this cute map https://www.loc.gov/law/help/miranda-warning-equivalents-abroad/miranda-equivalents-map.pdf

Comment: Possible dupe of; [Do we know all of the guarantees in the Constitution of the United Federation of Planets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89600/do-we-know-all-of-the-guarantees-in-the-constitution-of-the-united-federation-of)

Comment: There's another aspect to consider: DS9 is a Bajoran space station. So, whatever laws/rights/customs/whatevers that are given to suspects is derived by Bajoran laws and norms, not Federation law. So, while the Federation may normally inform a suspect of whatever rights they have, that might (probably) not occur on DS9 anyway since it's a Bajoran station that is partly administered by Starfleet.

Comment: @Valorum: I disagree with your dupe vote because my answer is valid for this question but not for the dupe target.

Comment: @Kevin - I didn't vote for it. I highlighted it as a possible dupe since my (gold tag badge) vote is binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, in the US, *Miranda* rights are attached to interrogations, not arrests.

One crewmember of the *Enterprise*-D was interrogated without being told of his right to remain silent, though he was offered a lawyer:

> PICARD: Please sit down, Mister Tarses. For the record, will you tell us your name and position?
>   TARSES: Simon Tarses, Crewman First Class, medical technician.
>   PICARD: I assure you this is an informal inquiry. We are not accusing you of anything. **However, if you would like counsel, it can be provided for you.**
>   TARSES: No, sir. I have nothing to hide.

Later, he invoked the right to remain silent on advice of counsel (again, he had not been previously advised of this right, so Riker had to tell him about it):

> PICARD: This hearing is convened on Stardate 44780 as a continuing inquiry into the activities of Crewman Simon Tarses. **Mister Tarses, for your own protection, I have assigned a counsel to you in the person of Commander William Riker.**
>   [...]
>   SABIN: Isn't it true that the paternal grandfather of whom you speak was not a Vulcan but was in fact a Romulan? That it is Romulan blood you carry and a Romulan heritage that you honour?
>   (Riker whispers in Simon's ear)
>   SABIN: We're waiting, Mister Tarses.
>   TARSES: **On the advice of my counsel I refuse to answer that question, in that the answer may serve to incriminate me.**

Later, we learn that Worf is aghast that he did this, but Picard defends it by calling it "the Seventh Guarantee" and also mentions a "Constitution" of some sort:

> WORF: He refused to answer the question about his Romulan grandfather.
>   PICARD: That is not a crime, Worf. Nor can we infer his guilt because he didn't respond.
>   WORF: Sir, if a man were not afraid of the truth, he would answer.
>   PICARD: Oh, no. We cannot allow ourselves think that. The **Seventh Guarantee** is one of the most important rights granted by the Federation. We cannot take a fundamental principle of **the Constitution** and turn it against a citizen.

**In conclusion**: The right to remain silent clearly exists, but it appears that Starfleet personnel do not need to be advised of it before being interrogated in a Starfleet setting.  The right to an attorney also exists, and it appears that personnel are routinely advised of that right (whether this is mandatory is less clear).  We do not know whether these rights also apply to civilians.  However, it seems unlikely that civilians would be accorded fewer rights than Starfleet personnel, in my entirely subjective opinion.

All quotes from *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode 4x21 "The Drumhead".

Comment: Minor semantic point, Tarsis is explicitly an enlisted crewman, not an officer.

Comment: @ench: Removed all mentions of "officer."

Answer (score 40):

Contrary to what you may think from watching TV, police officers are not required to issue the Miranda warning at the time of arrest; only [before beginning an interrogation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning#Circumstances_triggering_the_Miranda_requisites)

> The duty to warn only arises when police officers conduct custodial interrogations. **The Constitution does not require that a defendant be advised of the Miranda rights as part of the arrest procedure,** or once an officer has probable cause to arrest, or if the defendant has become a suspect of the focus of an investigation. Custody and interrogation are the events that trigger the duty to warn.

In addition, the Miranda Warning is an aspect of United States law.  Other countries do not necessarily have anything similar.  Considering that the United Federation of Planets represents **all of Earth's nations** - as well as several **alien planets and their nations** it's entirely probable that the legal proceedings of an arrest have changed significantly in between now and the time in which Star Trek is set.

In other words, we have no reason to assume they *should* be given such a warning.  The fact that they do not, in fact, issue such a warning would seem to stand as proof.

Comment: I find that very interesting, though. For a society that prides itself on being just, you would think these small details would matter even more so, and that it would have been legislated.

Comment: The second part, that the Miranda rights are very US centric, I think is spot on. Also, @Aurelius, the fact that you have a just society (the Federation) has nothing to do with the police informing you of your rights before an arrest. Many societies right now on Earth are also just, but don't have this either.

Comment: @Loki As per https://www.loc.gov/law/help/miranda-warning-equivalents-abroad/index.php `This report contains short summaries describing warnings similar to the Miranda warning that are required in 108 jurisdictions around the globe.` so the concept is not necessarily US centric.

Comment: @Aurelius One could argue that such "basic" laws and rights are taught to citizens as part of their education, such that the need to inform people becomes redundant.

Comment: @PeterM: I stand corrected! Unfortunately, I had the mistaken impression, due to Hollywood movies no doubt, that the Miranda rights are effective only during the arrest. I learned something today, thanks!

Comment: @Loki I only learnt it about 10 minutes ahead of you when I had the thought  'Do other countries have miranda rights?'  and I hit up google .. lol

Comment: @Mwr247 As per the link I posted, for some jurisdictions an arrest is only deemed legal if the equivalent miranda rights are read.

Comment: @PeterM I meant for Federation citizens, in response to Aurelius' comment. Certainly there are jurisdictions today that require Miranda-esque rights to be read, but the Federation might have found a way to make it obsolete without worrying about uninformed arrestees.

Comment: Or it is a further proof that Federation is a military dictatorship which (just as real ones) have mouth full of high values...

Comment: "The fact that they do not, in fact, issue such a warning would seem to stand as proof." In reference to DS9 specifically, that station is under Bajoran jurisdiction, not Federation. So, unfortunately, any on-screen interactions with suspects on the station is probably a poor example as we *should* be seeing the Bajoran criminal justice system in action, not the Federation's.

Comment: ....although the quote in the OP does say, "Federation law requires me to...". suggesting that they do have a similar law.

Comment: @colmde: The quote in the OP was, if I'm understanding it right, something the asker made up to explain what he was asking about, not something that has been shown in canon.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Ah yes, misread the post, sorry about that

Comment: -1: Correcting a misconception about the real-world counterpart is helpful, but you should follow that up with specific citations to one or more individual episodes, movies, etc.  High-level speculation about how you would theoretically expect the *Star Trek* world to look is an inadequate response to OP's question.

Answer (score 5):

"Miranda rights" is a misnomer — it is not a *right*, but a *procedure* that law enforcement officials have been required to follow to better ensure that things that actually *are* government-granted rights, such as the "right to remain silent", are not violated.

From a cynical point of view, the choice to read rights immediately upon arrest has nothing to do with protecting the rights of the arrested — given the procedure they are required to follow, reading the rights so early simply ensures law enforcement can use as evidence anything the arrested says while mouthing off in the police car.

Given the somewhat idyllic view of society portrayed by many Star Trek series, one can easily imagine that individuals are generally better informed, that law enforcement procedures are more just and fair, and officials are more sensitive to the rights of the accused, so there simply is no *need* for any procedure resembling the Miranda warning; such a thing would be entirely superfluous, and its requirement would do more harm than good.

Comment: This is fair, but I also believe that DS9 missed lots of opportunities to really explore how a loosely-governed outpost would repeatedly grate against the Federation sensibilities of its Starfleet commander in areas of commerce, law, and personal rights.

Comment: @Hurkyl your semantic rant at the beginning has little relevance here, and is wrong. The Miranda v. Arizona case established that an individual under arrest has the right to know their rights. If anything, it should be called the Miranda right, but I think the conventional "Miranda rights" is a sufficient term.

Comment: @TBear: I disagree that it's irrelevant. the OP is phrased as if the Miranda warning itself is a 'basic human right' that deserves protecting, and that misconception needs to be dispelled to address the implicit idea that it's something that the federation *should* do. Okay, I suppose  that comment is irrelevant if one doesn't see that premise implicit in the OP and thus the need to address it... but I do find it present and worth addressing.

Comment: @Hurkyl but the Miranda v. Arizona case established that the Miranda warning *is* a basic human right, according to the U.S. supreme court, to all who are interrogated or incarcerated. Many obviously guilty people walk free today because their right to hear that warning was violated. I do not believe the OP was implicitly or explicitly asking whether "Miranda rights" are actually rights under the U.S. government today, OP is asking whether the Federation extends those same rights.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I don't think this is a misnomer. Constitutional law **itself** is not a law, but it is a list of laws. Miranda rights are not a right, but they are (a list of) rights. Although it is of course possible for people to misinterpret it regardless of the specific semantics :)

Answer (score 5):

I was just watching the Voyager episode [Meld](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Meld_(episode)) and I noted that when Tuvok is charging Suder with murder, he says...

> **TUVOK:** *I must advise you that under Starfleet Directive one zero one you do not have to answer any questions.*

Comment: Good find. This certain seems to suggest a set of standard "rights", albeit these are starfleet regulations rather than Federation Law.

Comment: This is interesting, since Suder was a Maquis, not Starfleet. So it makes sense for Tuvok to explain his rights, where a career officer or enlisted crew member would have presumably already known this.